# Getting forbidden error while using nginx inside docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

My Docker file contents are

```
FROM nginx
COPY /src /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My docker compose file contents are

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: app:1.0.0
    volumes:
    - ./src:/usr/share/nginx/html
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
```

I'm getting following error when run docker-compose

```
*1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden
```

I tried giving permission to directory -> /usr/share/nginx/html
it didn't work.

I want to  sync host directory with docker container.

Comment: Does you `src` contains a `index.html` file? If not, please create a sample file & test it.

Comment: You do not need to use `COPY` if you are using `volume` for `src` folder in docker compose.

Comment: yes src folder contains index.html

Comment: Following this youtube video..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSyIE-bTt5U

Comment: This works for me, not sure what actually is getting missed.

Answer (score 16):

I was facing the same issue so the posting answer might help some else or some else looking for the same problem

I am running nginx official image.

```
docker run --rm --name some-nginx -p 8080:80 -v /test/html5-youtube.js/examples/:/usr/share/nginx/html -it nginx
```

I was getting this error.

```
[error] 8#8: *3 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is *forbidden*, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
```

So when I check the directory permission it was wrong.

[image]

Check the user in nginx.conf in my case it is nginx so change file permission.

```
cd /usr/share/nginx/html
chown nginx:nginx ./*
```

and then I was able to get a response from the server.

```
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Oct/2018:09:04:52 +0000] "GET /html5-youtube.js HTTP/1.1" 404 571 "http://localhost:8080/player.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

**Update:**

Or add the permission at build time if you are not using bind volume.

```
RUN chown nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/*
```

Comment: Do we need to do this everytime for every new container spinning up?

Comment: @JananathBanuka yes, but you can avoid this every time if you add in the Dockerfile. please check if the updated answer.