# Docker angular nginx return 403 Forbidden

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I am trying to configure angular with docker image and run with `docker-compose`.

Here is my dockerfile

```
# Use official node image as the base image
FROM node:16-alpine3.12 as build

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# Add the source code to app
COPY ./ ./

# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build:prod


# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server

# Use official nginx image as the base image
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy the build output to replace the default nginx contents.
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
#COPY /nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Assign permisson 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254476/getting-forbidden-error-while-using-nginx-inside-docker
# RUN chown nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

It runs correctly if I run `docker build` and `docker run` locally. But, after push to github with yml below:

```
name: Docker Image CI For Web

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'web-v*'

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: edward8520/meekou
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: ./angular/
          file: ./angular/Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

And then run `docker-compose` with below,

```
version: '3.9'
services:
    meekou-web:
        container_name: 'meekou-web-test'
        image: 'edward8520/meekou:web-v0.0.4'
        ports: 
            - "8888:80"
            - "8889:443"
        environment:
          - NODE_ENV=production
        volumes:
          - ./meekou-web/:/usr/share/nginx/html
        expose:
          - "80"
          - "443"
```

It throw error `403 Forbidden`

Comment: I am unable to pull down the image from DockerHub. Could you open up the permissions?

Comment: @MrDiggles I think this is not project specific issue, you can make a test with any angular and dockerhub