# Gitub Action npm install Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/services/meekouapi.ts' in '/usr/local/app'

Tags: webpack, dockerfile, office-js, github-actions, excel-addins

I am trying deploy Excel Addin to docker image.

The command `npm run build:prod` and `docker build -t excel .` in local environment works.

But, it will fail with the Github action below:

```
name: Docker Image CI For Excel

on:
  push:
    tags:
      - 'excel-v*'

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: xxx/xx
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@ad44023a93711e3deb337508980b4b5e9bcdc5dc
        with:
          context: ./
          file: ./Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
```

Here is the error from Github Action

```
#13 [build 5/5] RUN npm run build:prod
#13 0.626 
#13 0.626 > excel-custom-functions@2.0.0 build:prod
#13 0.626 > webpack --mode production
#13 0.626 
#13 12.02 assets by status 217 KiB [cached] 22 assets
#13 12.02 runtime modules 221 bytes 1 module
#13 12.02 modules by path ./node_modules/core-js/modules/*.js 243 KiB 230 modules
#13 12.02 modules by path ./node_modules/core-js/internals/*.js 158 KiB 177 modules
#13 12.02 modules by path ./src/ 17 KiB
#13 12.02   modules with errors 117 bytes [errors] 3 modules
#13 12.02   modules by path ./src/services/*.ts 5.36 KiB
#13 12.02     ./src/services/common.model.ts 266 bytes [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02     ./src/services/http.ts 5.1 KiB [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02   ./src/functions/functions.ts 3.54 KiB [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02   ./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts 4.3 KiB [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02   ./src/pages/data-from-web/data-from-web.ts 3.68 KiB [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02 ./node_modules/core-js/stable/index.js 9.62 KiB [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02 ./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js 24 KiB [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02 ./node_modules/node-fetch/browser.js 732 bytes [built] [code generated]
#13 12.02 
#13 12.02 ERROR in ./src/commands/commands.ts
#13 12.02 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
#13 12.02 Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /usr/local/app/src/commands/commands.ts.
#13 12.02     at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:52:18)
#13 12.02     at successLoader (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:39:5)
#13 12.02     at Object.loader (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:5)
#13 12.02 
#13 12.02 ERROR in ./src/dialog/dialog.ts
#13 12.02 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
#13 12.02 Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /usr/local/app/src/dialog/dialog.ts.
#13 12.02     at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:52:18)
#13 12.02     at successLoader (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:39:5)
#13 12.02     at Object.loader (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:5)
#13 12.02 
#13 12.02 ERROR in ./src/login/login.ts
#13 12.02 Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
#13 12.02 Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /usr/local/app/src/login/login.ts.
#13 12.02     at makeSourceMapAndFinish (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:52:18)
#13 12.02     at successLoader (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:39:5)
#13 12.02     at Object.loader (/usr/local/app/node_modules/ts-loader/dist/index.js:22:5)
#13 12.02 
#13 12.02 ERROR in meekou
#13 12.02 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/services/meekouapi.ts' in '/usr/local/app'
#13 12.02 
#13 12.02 ERROR in meekou
#13 12.02 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/shared/appconsts.ts' in '/usr/local/app'
```

Here is the dockerfile

```
# Use official node image as the base image
FROM node:16-alpine3.12 as build

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/app

# Add the source code to app
COPY ./ ./

# Install all the dependencies
RUN npm install

# Generate the build of the application
RUN npm run build:prod


# Stage 2: Serve app with nginx server

# Use official nginx image as the base image
FROM nginx:latest

# Copy the build output to replace the default nginx contents.
COPY --from=build /usr/local/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
#COPY /nginx.conf  /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
# Assign permisson 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49254476/getting-forbidden-error-while-using-nginx-inside-docker
# RUN chown nginx:nginx /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```